# Sanhedrin Redefining the simple translation of a Passuk

Tags: sources-mekorot, halacha-theory, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, mussar-ethics, beit-din-court

The Sanhedrin are empowered with the capability of defining a certain word or verse in the Torah through a Drasha exegesis (cf. [Hilkhot Mamrim 1:3](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/e301.htm)).

Firstly, does this mean that before the Sanhedrin came to reinterpret this word or verse it was understood in its literal sense? (For instance, did Ayin Tachat Ayin Mamash -eye for an eye literally- ever transpire?)

Secondly, is there a source for the idea that the Sanhedrin reinterpreted this certain verse or word from the literal translation in response to changing ethical norms and more progressive values? (Namely, Ayin Tachat Ayin was looked at as barbaric and Sanhedrin therefore solved the problem by diverting it's translation...)

Comment: Adding sources for the claims you make would greatly improve your question.

Comment: Anyone is welcome to edit as they wish and provide sources ...

Comment: Making claims, without having checked them for accuracy, does not make your question [a good question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "Secondly, is there a source for the idea that the Sanhedrin reinterpreted this certain verse or word from the literal translation in response to changing ethical norms and more progressive values?" though i do not have a source for this yet, i believe this is the only rational approach as how to explain the contradiction between peshat and derash according to the understanding of the Rashbam (where peshat is totally independent of derash, and sometimes even contradicts Halacha. see his commentary on ועבדו לעולם and on tefillin). see also ramabm moreh 3:41 on ayin tachas ayin.

Comment: I know the claim is true and accurate. I just don't have the source on hand. I think it is Rambam Hilchot Mamrim Perek 1 Halacha 1-2 IIRC...

Comment: the gemara in menahot 29b also suggests that Halacha evolved through the generations

Comment: Or it could be that this is how the Sanhedrin _always_ interpreted the Psukim. Or it could be that they re-interpreted the verses for textual reasons. Or it could be that they re-interpreted the verses to fit into existing Halacha LeMoshe MiSinai. Or it could be an Asmachta and truly _be_ a Halacha LeMoshe MiSinai.

Comment: I don't think that poking out an eye was _that_ barbaric in the Roman times (Herod did it) and it's quite _mild_ compared to contemporary punishments.

Comment: see also makkot 7a. suggests that the death penalty was too barbaric and that chazal intentionally minimized it as much as possible.

Comment: when the gamaro brings down a posuq(im) for a statement which was said, it is not to show that the law is learned from this posuq(im) but it is this posuq(im) which is attached to the statement as a reminder for the people that are remembering the law ba'al pa. remember that the gamaro was oral and therefore people needed ways to remember the halokhoth stated in names of various hakhom zl. the laws were already established and older but they were attached to a posuq(im) as a reminder

Comment: Both R. Dr. Haym Soloveitchik and R. Dr. Jose Faur argue that the ben sorer umoreh law was viewed as unethical, and therfore interpreted out of existence.

Comment: Consider clarifying whether answers such as the information on my previous comment are acceptable or whether you are only looking for information regarding an eye for an eye.

Comment: Does not have to be specific to Ayin Tachat Ayin. Any generic answer will work. I want a source to the idea that the Sanhedrin saw a Torah law as unethical and therefore used their power to reinterpret the "regressive" law.